# Missing storage space in Android 7.0

Tags: storage

[image]

Where did all the missing space go? I've deleted most of my apps, but no matter how much I get rid of it keeps saying I'm almost out. The stuff I have accounts for 3.5 GB-ish, but there's lots that seems to have disappeared. The version is Android 7.0; the phone is a Samsung Galaxy S5.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: You added the tag `storage` to your question, and there are nearly 500 questions associated with that tag. Have you investigated those, even only the ones with accepted answers? Hover over the tag and click the link `view tag` to take you to a list of related questions to explore.

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this before!
Anyways here is the steps i would do:

**1.** If you are sure that the 15.9/16GB is wrong, e.g you know you haven't got that many apps/videos, then proceed to step 3.

**2.** If you know you have got like more than 50 apps or really many videos, take some time and delete videos/apps (of course images, otger files too) that take much storage.

**3.** Go to **Setting > Device Mainteance** and then clean everything you can (optimize the phone)

**4.** If that doesn't work go to like a phone reparator and check what they can do.